# ruta de acceso del archivo de informe no válida crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo el siguiente código que me realiza la carga en el .rpt mediante un procedimiento almacenado.

```
 private void Frm_Impresion_Presupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CODPRE", SecPre));
                da.Fill(ds, "fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion");
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR : NO HAY DATOS", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
                //Cargar el Reporte
                String filePath = @"D:\Reporte\Reporte_Presupuesto.rpt";
                //rd.Load(Application.StartupPath.ToString()+ "\\frm\\Reporte_Presupuesto.rpt");
                rd.Load(filePath);
                //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                rd.SetDataSource(ds);
                //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument 
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y posteriormente tengo el siguiente codigo para exportar

```
   private void BtnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rde = new ReportDocument();
        string nombre = "Presupuesto Nº " + SecPre + ".pdf";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = nombre;
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
                DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = ruta;
                Console.WriteLine(ruta);
                CrExportOptions = rde.ExportOptions;
                {
                    CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                    CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                    CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                    CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                }
                rde.Export();
                MessageBox.Show("La Exportacion ha Finalizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Al momento de realizar la exportación me arroja el mensaje ruta de acceso del archivo de informe no válida, que podría estar realizando mal en el código o que ruta esta tomando para realizar la exportación.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Has probado de ejecutar la aplicación con permisos de administrador? Puede que el error sea que no tiene permisos para escribir en esa carpeta que le indicas

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos problemas.

1. No estas usando correctamente saveFileDialog1. saveFileDialog1.FileName devuelve el nombre del documento que tu has seleccionado para guardar un documento después de ejecutar ShowDialog, y tu le estas asignando un nombre y luego muestras el dialogo. Yo usaría mejor FolderShowDialog
2. Da igual lo que lo que elijas en el saveFileDialog1 porque luego lo exportas a en esta línea a lo que hay en ruta:

   CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = ruta;
   A parte tienes un error aqui:

   CrExportOptions = rde.ExportOptions;
   {
   CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
   CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
   CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
   CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
   }
   rde.Export();

Has puesto el ; en la primera línea por lo que las opciones no las está cogiendo.

Prueba este código, no está compilado

```
 private void BtnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) 
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ReportDocument rde = new ReportDocument();
            string nombre = "Presupuesto Nº " + SecPre + ".pdf";
            string ruta = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            ruta = ruta + "\\" + nombre;
            try
            {
                ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
                DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = ruta;
                Console.WriteLine(ruta);
                CrExportOptions = rde.ExportOptions
                {
                    CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                    CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                    CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                    CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                }
                rde.Export();
                MessageBox.Show("La Exportacion ha Finalizado", "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
   
    
}
```